# UIView as a SCNGeometry's diffuse material glitch

Tags: ios, uikit, scenekit

I use a `UIView` as a diffuse material for a `SCNPlane` so I can display a 2D menu inside my 3D scene.

This works as I expected :

```
var node:SCNNode = // A child of my ARSCNView's scene
var menuVC:UIViewController = // I keep a strong reference to this view controller

let menuPlane:SCNPlane = // Newly created plane
menuPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = menuVC.view
let menuPlaneNode = SCNNode(geometry: menuPlane)
menuPlaneNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
node.addChildNode(menuPlaneNode)
```

However, I can notice a "flash" when the node is added to the scene; further inspection reveals it is the view of `menuVC` displayed in fullscreen in front of the `ARSCNView` for 1 frame, then it is rendered inside the scene.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, in the Storyboard, setting the **simulated size** of the view controller to **Freeform** instead of Fixed solves the issue :

[image]

I have no clue why though.